# Retrieve issuer name from certificate by SecCertificate

Tags: ios, swift, character-encoding, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate file. SecCertificate object is created correctly.

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!)
let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, data! as CFData)

▿ Optional<SecCertificateRef>
  - some : <cert(0x7fec5d608250) s: www.google.com i: Avast trusted CA>

//   I can get Subject name by 
SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificate!)! as String

//   I tried printing SecCertificateCopyNormalizedIssuerSequence
var data1 = SecCertificateCopyNormalizedIssuerSequence(certificate!)! as Data
print(String(data: data1, encoding: .utf8))

Optional("0h1\u{0B}0\t\u{06}\u{03}U\u{04}\u{06}\u{13}\u{02}CZ1\u{0F}0\r\u{06}\u{03}U\u{04}\u{08}\u{0C}\u{06}Prague1\u{0E}0\u{0C}\u{06}\u{03}U\u{04}\n\u{0C}\u{05}AVAST1\u{1D}0\u{1B}\u{06}\u{03}U\u{04}\u{0B}\u{0C}\u{14}Software Development1\u{19}0\u{17}\u{06}\u{03}U\u{04}\u{03}\u{0C}\u{10}Avast trusted CA")
```

But I need to get issuers name info like common name or organisation(like i from SecCertificateRef in above example) using SecCertificate.h

Thanks.